# Generating a block matrix from the given matrix valued function

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra

I have the following problem. I have some function A(l, l') which is the NxN matrix, and l, I run over some set (say -M, ..., M). I'm interested in generating a block matrix (B)(l, l')=A(l, l') (in the above example it has the dimension (2M+1)Nx(2M+1)N) whose l, l' the block is given by A(l, l'). As far as I can tell there is no standard function that does that (although it seems to me to be a natural way one gets a block matrix - in terms of its blocks). Things like NumPy block and NumPy concatenate do not seem to be capable of doing that (feel free to correct me if I'm wrong). Can someone help me to sort that out or point me in the right direction?

I'm new to python and this community, so do not judge me too much.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you please show an example input and expected output?

Comment: The thing is that I do not know what to input so far. I just have A(l, l') given and want to generate a block matrix out of it and struggle to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this [numpy.bmat](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bmat.html) in the following way

```
B = np.bmat([[A(i,j) for j in range(-M, M+1)] for i in range(-M, M+1)])
```

This first creates a list of lists of matrices, then uses bmat to place them side by side

Comment: Great thanks! Super simple as it turns out.

Comment: Thank you, and wellcome to the community.